How to write vertical line "evaluated at" symbol?
I figured out the LaTeX for the lower bound. the "|_ {n}" part of x^ze^{-x}|_{n}

I need an upper bound of infinity. How would I write that?

Use the ^ symbol: |_{n}^\infty

here is what it will look like! x^ze^{-x} |_n^\infty $x^ze^{-x} |_n^\infty$ You can also use \mid instead of |.

For LaTeX related questions, please use https://tex.stackexchange.com/

I'd suggest \left.x^ze^{-x}\right|_n^\infty -- it looks like $$\left.x^ze^{-x}\right|_n^\infty$$ with the \mid adjusted to the height of the expression on the left

Instead of |, you can also use \big{|}, \Big{|}, \bigg{|} or \Bigg{|}.

Seconding@AlexeyBurdin's answer - it is the one that will scale well with the enclosed text, and the fact that you can use "." to specify an invisible left encloser is a nice thing to learn. (Yes, I did once spend 20 minutes trying to figure this out. Why do you ask? :-)

That's an awful lot of answering in the comments.  Would any one of you care to post a summarizing Answer?

Thank you for your answers!

You can also use \big{vert_n} : $x^ze^{-x}\vert_{n}$
